# Cannot update objects via rails console (or through my app) ... but no specific errors to help debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

here's what I tried to do:

```
irb(main):008:0> c.title = "Another Test"
=> "Another Test"
irb(main):009:0> c.save
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  FriendlyId::Slug Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "friendly_id_slugs".* FROM "friendly_id_slugs" WHERE "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = 'Contest' AND (slug = 'another-test-challenge' OR slug LIKE 'another-test-challenge--%') AND (sluggable_id <> 64) ORDER BY LENGTH(slug) DESC, slug DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

When I try to do this in my app (i.e. using an edit form), I get this issue:

```
2013-01-10T17:53:47+00:00 app[web.2]: cache: [POST /mycontroller/this-is-the-old-title] invalidate, pass
```

I can't seem to edit the title for my object, which is equivalent to the friendly id associated to my object as well.

Comment: After you run that command in the rails console what does `c.errors.full_messages` output?

Comment: Or try running the command with `c.save!` instead.

Comment: Leo - thanks for pointing that out, it helped figure out what was going on! If you put your response as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For your answer `c.save` will call validations on that object. If any validations fail it will rollback the SQL transaction.

If your transaction gets `ROLLBACK` you can ask the object `c.errors.full_messages` to see the errors and which validations failed or instead of using `c.save` use `c.save!` which will raise an exception if validations fail.